# Need Assistance on How to Close Parent JFrame from within JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've searched and could not find the answer I need to do the following:  I have two java files:  one JFrame, one JPanel.  I configured a button in the JFrame to open up the JPanel from within the main frame with a new size of 800,800.  Now, I want to close the JPanel and go  back to the original JFrame (the one that originally was at size 500,500 with an image).  It seems simply straightforward, but I've created an instance of the main frame from within the JPanel and set the jPanel to (`this.setVisible(false)`).  I created a new jFrame object and set its visibility to true.  What happens is, a new instance of the JFrame appears alright, but the JFrame at 800,800 with no image still appears as well.  I've tried several configurations of `getContentPane()`, `setContentPane()` and even tried passing a JFrame parameter to the constructor of the JPanel.  I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this, but any help would be much appreciated.  All I want is the original JFrame with the original size and image displayed.  Thank you in advance.

```
private void jButton_closeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    this.setVisible(false);
    mainMenuFrame = new MainMenuFrame();
    mainMenuFrame.setVisible(true);
    invalidate(); validate();
    repaint();

}
```

Comment: Basically, I have this in my JPanel file:

Comment: private void jButton_closeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        
        this.setVisible(false);
        mainMenuFrame = new MainMenuFrame();
        mainMenuFrame.setVisible(true);
        invalidate(); validate();
        repaint();
        
    }

Comment: edit your question to add code. if you open and close the JPanel from your jframe? would that be a possibility?

Comment: I am going to try closing from within the frame instead.  Thank you.

Comment: i made an answer which you can upvote. if you have more question feel free to ask. aslo if you run into trouble on implementing this, post the code so we can help you better

Comment: Thank you, just voted for ya.....this works much better.

Comment: so the problem is solved already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could open and close the jpanel from within your JFrame. the button would be also added to the jframe instead of the jpanel. for easier accessing use the jpanel as member variable

Comment: if not tell me and post the code you are struggeling with

Comment: I will close from within main frame.